# Unstable calculation error

Tags: c#, matrix

I need to calculate matrix: (  **X^(T)**  *  **X**   )**^(-1)**.
Legend for the code&comments:

```
x is double[,] array;
xT - transposed matrix
^(-1) - inverted matrix
```

Every time i generate new random matrix to work with it and i found out that program is very unstable, because it isn't working properly with any input data. I'm sure about that because i need to get Identity matrix in the end if everything's fine, but sometimes i get a totally terrible Ineverted matrix so i don't get an Identity matrix. I'm dissappointes because i always use the same type of data and do not convert anything. Compiler is MVS 2010. Hope You will help me.

Here is my **Program.cs**:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Matrix x = new Matrix(5, 4);
        //Matrix temp = new Matrix(x.Row, x.Col);
        //double[] y = new double[x.Row];
        //double[] b = new double[x.Row];

        //this data isn't calculated correctly. used for debugging
        x.MatrixX[0, 0] = 7; x.MatrixX[0, 1] = 6; x.MatrixX[0, 2] = 5; x.MatrixX[0, 3] = 8;
        x.MatrixX[1, 0] = 7; x.MatrixX[1, 1] = 5; x.MatrixX[1, 2] = 8; x.MatrixX[1, 3] = 5;
        x.MatrixX[2, 0] = 6; x.MatrixX[2, 1] = 8; x.MatrixX[2, 2] = 6; x.MatrixX[2, 3] = 8;
        x.MatrixX[3, 0] = 8; x.MatrixX[3, 1] = 5; x.MatrixX[3, 2] = 8; x.MatrixX[3, 3] = 7;
        x.MatrixX[4, 0] = 8; x.MatrixX[4, 1] = 5; x.MatrixX[4, 2] = 6; x.MatrixX[4, 3] = 7;
        /*
        7,00000  6,00000  5,00000  8,00000
        7,00000  5,00000  8,00000  5,00000
        6,00000  8,00000  6,00000  8,00000
        8,00000  5,00000  8,00000  7,00000
        8,00000  5,00000  6,00000  7,00000
        */


        //random matrix generation
        /*
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < x.Row; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < x.Col; j++)
                x.MatrixX[i, j] = rnd.Next(5, 10);
         */


        /*i'm going to calculate: (  X^(T)  *  X  )^(-1)
         * 1. transpose X
         * 2. multiply X and (1)
         * 3. invert matrix (2)
         * +4. i wanna check the results: Multilate of (2) and (3) = Identity_matrix.
         * */
        Matrix.Display(x);

        //1
        Matrix xt = Matrix.Transpose(x);
        Matrix.Display(xt);

        //2
        Matrix xxt = Matrix.Multiply(x, xt);
        Matrix.Display(xxt);

        //3
        Matrix xxtinv = Matrix.Invert(Matrix.Multiply(x, xt));
        Matrix.Display(xxtinv);

        //4
        Console.WriteLine("Invert(xxt) * xxt. IdentityMatrix:");
        Matrix IdentityMatrix = Matrix.Multiply(xxtinv, xxt);
        Matrix.Display(IdentityMatrix);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

And here is **Matrix.cs** with all functions:

```
public class Matrix
    {
        private double[,] matrix;
        private int row;
        private int col;

        #region constructors
        public Matrix(int Row, int Col)
        {
            this.row = Row;
            this.col = Col;
            matrix = new double[Row, Col];
        }

        public Matrix()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            Row = rnd.Next(3, 7);
            Col = rnd.Next(3, 7);
            matrix = new double[Row, Col];
            for (int i = 0; i < Row; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < Col; j++)
                    matrix[i, j] = rnd.Next(5, 10);
        }

        public Matrix(Matrix a)
        {
            this.Col = a.Col;
            this.Row = a.Row;
            this.matrix = a.matrix;
        }
        #endregion

        #region properties
        public int Col
        {
            get { return col; }
            set { col = value; }
        }
        public int Row
        {
            get { return row; }
            set { row = value; }
        }
        public double[,] MatrixX
        {
            get { return matrix; }
            set { matrix = value; }
        }
        #endregion

        static public Matrix Transpose(Matrix array)
        {
            Matrix temp = new Matrix(array.Col, array.Row);
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Row; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < array.Col; j++)
                    temp.matrix[j, i] = array.matrix[i, j];
            return temp;
        }

        static public void Display(Matrix array)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Row; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < array.Col; j++)
                    Console.Write("{0,5:f2}\t", array.matrix[i, j]);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        static public Matrix Multiply(Matrix a, Matrix b)
        {
            if (a.Col != b.Row) throw new Exception("multiplication is impossible: a.Col != b.Row");

            Matrix r = new Matrix(a.Row, b.Col);
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Row; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < b.Col; j++)
                {
                    double sum = 0;
                    for (int k = 0; k < b.Row; k++)
                        sum += a.matrix[i, k] * b.matrix[k, j];
                    r.matrix[i, j] = sum;
                }
            }
            return r;
        }

        static public Matrix Invert(Matrix a)
        {
            Matrix E = new Matrix(a.Row, a.Col);
            double temp = 0;
            int n = a.Row;


            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    E.matrix[i, j] = 0.0;

                    if (i == j)
                        E.matrix[i, j] = 1.0;
                }

            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
            {
                temp = a.matrix[k, k];

                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    a.matrix[k, j] /= temp;
                    E.matrix[k, j] /= temp;
                }

                for (int i = k + 1; i < n; i++)
                {
                    temp = a.matrix[i, k];

                    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                    {
                        a.matrix[i, j] -= a.matrix[k, j] * temp;
                        E.matrix[i, j] -= E.matrix[k, j] * temp;
                    }
                }
            }

            for (int k = n - 1; k > 0; k--)
            {
                for (int i = k - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    temp = a.matrix[i, k];

                    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                    {
                        a.matrix[i, j] -= a.matrix[k, j] * temp;
                        E.matrix[i, j] -= E.matrix[k, j] * temp;
                    }
                }
            }


            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    a.matrix[i, j] = E.matrix[i, j];
                }

            return a;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The Jama package might be good alternative for matrix calculations in Java: http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/  Compared to your "Invert" routine, Jama uses a different approach based on LU and QR decomposition.

Comment: @AxelKemper This is C#, not Java.

Comment: Oops! Sorry abouting mixing up C# and Java. The following Article contains a rather simple C# implementation for matrix calculations: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9088/Application-of-Fraction-class-Matrix-class-in-C  The implementation of "Inverse" is probably a bit naive (via determinants) but this could make it even more suitable for learning purposes. A more efficient "InverseFast" is also included.

Comment: @AxelKemper I would be very glad is you advise me such a good library for C#. :3 P.S. It's a pity, but this c# soluting isn't usefull for me because it uses determinants so it doesn't solve the main problem. P.S.S. I'm generating double numbers for my matrix now and it's fine. Anyway, this is not a solution. I'd be pleased if you find any good library for this purposes. Thanks for help!

Comment: A port of Jama from Java to C# is described here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5835/DotNetMatrix-Simple-Matrix-Library-for-NET

Comment: @AxelKemper THanks You a lot! I should start thinking before inventing a wheel :D

Comment: @AxelKemper It seems that i need to get at least 15 point of reputation myself to have a right to vote. :( Explain me, please, how to vote Your comment up if i'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, the determinant of x * transpose(x) is zero. As a result, there is no inverse, which is probably why you're getting strange results.

I also note that your `Inverse` function modifies the matrix passed to it. This should probably be modified to avoid that.